# How to horizontally align multiple apex pie chart

Tags: css, reactjs, apexcharts

I'm using [ReactApexChart](https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/pie-charts/simple-pie-chart/) for showing pie charts in a react app. I want four pie charts to be horizontally aligned inside a single `div` but by-default it creates the charts with vertical alignment with a new `div` each time. The documentation doesn't do any help.

```
render() {
        const { isLoading } = this.state;

        const options = {
            labels: ['Dynatrace', 'Splunk', 'Status cake', 'Datadog'],
            responsive: [{
              breakpoint: 480,
              options: {
                chart: {
                  width: 200
                },
                legend: {
                  position: 'bottom'
                }
              },
            }]
          };

        const series = [44, 55, 13, 43];

        return(
            <Fragment>
                {
                    isLoading && <Loader />
                }
                <div>
                 <ReactApexChart options={options} series={series} type="pie" width="380" />
                 <ReactApexChart options={options} series={series} type="pie" width="380" />
                 <ReactApexChart options={options} series={series} type="pie" width="380" />
                 <ReactApexChart options={options} series={series} type="pie" width="380" />
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried going into the inspector and adding something like display: inline-block; to the apex chart divs?

Comment: @brooksrelyt yes, it only adds max 3 pie charts as inline, the 4th one always comes in next line

Comment: @izengod can you show your `divStyle` and what size browser are you trying to get them to fit 4 across?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an import to a CSS file (for example: MyCharts.css)
2. In the div tag you created add a className (for example: charts):

```
import "./MyCharts.css";

// The rest of the code I didn't change, but of course you need to add it as well

<div className="charts">
    <ReactApexChart options={options} series={series} type="pie" width="380" />
    <ReactApexChart options={options} series={series} type="pie" width="380" />
    <ReactApexChart options={options} series={series} type="pie" width="380" />
    <ReactApexChart options={options} series={series} type="pie" width="380" />
</div>

// The rest of the code I didn't change, but of course you need to add it as well
```

3. Create a CSS file (for example: MyCharts.css) and put in it the following settings:

```css
.charts div {
    display: inline-block;

    /*
        An option, if you want to add text horizontally to the charts,
        so that the charts appears in the middle of the text line
    */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```